# Writer fields are showing description instead of expected values

Tags: windows-xp, openoffice, openoffice-writer

My fields appear to have broken in OpenOffice.org Writer. They no longer display what they're supposed to but instead show some sort of description of their function.

For instance, instead of page numbers, I get `Page numbers`, not any actual page numbers.

[image: The page numbers field broken in OpenOffice.org]

Any idea how to fix this? Known bug, did I accidentally set something wrong, or what?

And I did try restarting OpenOffice and then my laptop. Using Windows XP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went to go print what I was working on and boom! It notifies me that

> **Show field commands** option is checked

That sounded like what might be causing the problem. So thanks to [this OpenOffice.org mail thread](http://www.openoffice.org/servlets/ReadMsg?list=users&msgNo=100268), I turned it off at:

> View > Field Names

Now my fields are displaying properly.